# How to dynamically reposition UIButton as subview of UIImageView when rotating

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios5

I'm working on an iPad app that lets you control different things in a prototype of an intelligent house. For example it lets you turn lights on and off. For this, I have made a `UIImageView` that shows the floor plan of the house and added `UIButtons` as subviews for each lamp that can be toggled.

[image]

As you can see the buttons are placed perfectly on the floor plan using the `setFrame` method of each `UIButton`. However, when I rotate the iPad to portrait orientation, the following happens:

[image]

The buttons obviously still have the same origin, however it is not relative to the repositioning of the image.

The floor plan image has the following settings for struts and springs:

[image]

and has its content mode set to `Aspect Fit`.

### My question is

how do I dynamically reposition each `UIButton`, such that it has the same relative position. I figure I have to handle this in the `{did/should}AutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` delegate method.

It should be noted that the `UIImageView` is zoomable and to handle this I have implemented the `scrollViewDidZoom` delegate method as follows:

```
for (UIView *button in _floorPlanImage.subviews) {       
    CGRect oldFrame = button.frame;
    [button.layer setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 1)];
    button.frame = oldFrame;
    button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0/scrollView.zoomScale, 1.0/scrollView.zoomScale);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried un ticking the autoresize sub views for that view?

Comment: Excellent question, perfectly explained and illustrated.

Comment: @LuisOscar Yes, I have tried to do that without any success, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the best way to layout subviews is in the `- (void) layoutSubviews` method. You will have to subclass your UIImageView and override the method.

This method will automatically get called whenever your frame changes and also gets called the first time your view gets presented.

If you put all your layout code in this method, it prevents layout fragmentation and repetition, keeps your view code in your views, and most things just work by default.

Comment: Sounds like a very good approach! 
However, do you have any suggestions for what the code in the `layoutSubviews` would look like, such that the buttons will appear to be positioned in the same place as before rotation? Are there some APIs for doing this dynamically?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Zappel Well, what I would suggest is to only position the buttons in `layoutSubviews` based on the internal data of your app. It sounds (although I'm not completely sure) that your position data currently only lives in the view object, which can be a bad idea if the view controller decides to let go of the view during low memory or for other reasons.

Comment: @Zappel If you want to just update the locations without refactoring where the data is kept, you should look at the contentMode property of your UIImageView and reposition your buttons based on that (with manual calculations). However, I would recommend moving the data.

Comment: The position data is not a part the view object. I have an object called `FloorPlanButton`, which inherits from `UIButton` and has some custom properties - including a `CGPoint`, which contains the position of the individual buttons.
I just thought that there might exist some clever way of calculating the new position of each button, relative to position before rotation?

Comment: @Zappel OK, that sounds good. What I'm suggesting is just to move whatever code positions the buttons in the first place into the layoutSubviews method, then the position will get updated based on the data whenever it needs to.

Comment: Yes, I follow you on that approach. The buttons have a predefined position i landscape view. What I am asking is if there are any smart ways of calculating the new position relative to the original position and to the `frame` and/or `bounds` of the view containing them? Thanks